# Simple HTML, CSS and Javascript image viewer - scrollbars missing in fullscreen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to implement a simple Imageviewer that displays an image that fits screen and when clicked, the image shoud be shown in fullsize.

Everything almost works, but when image is displayed in full-size, there are no scrollbars, so I can only see the center of the image and not explore the rest.

```js
const image = document.getElementById("image");
const imageContainer = document.getElementById("image-container");

image.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (image.classList.contains("full-size")) {
    image.classList.remove("full-size");
    imageContainer.classList.remove("full-size");
  } else {
    image.classList.add("full-size");
    imageContainer.classList.add("full-size");
  }
});
```

```css
#image-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#image {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transition: transform .5s;
  cursor: zoom-in;
}

#image.full-size {
  cursor: zoom-out;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 10;
  transform: scale(2);
}

#image-container.full-size {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="image-container">
  <img id="image" src="https://bigbookofamigahardware.com/bboah/media/download_photos/cybervisppc_4_big.jpg">
</div>
```

The implementaion can be seen here:

https://codepen.io/bobittjek/pen/qBMWpdy

Comment: change `#image.full-size {
  cursor: zoom-out;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 10;
  transform: scale(2);
} ` remove `position: fixed;`

Comment: https://codepen.io/mahdibagheri71/pen/NWLKXgR

Comment: If you will remove `position:fixed` from `#image.full-size` then scroll will appear on zoom.